# i cant pass a parameter to a function using javascript

Tags: javascript, function, web, parameters

i am trying to add a set time out function like this and it does not work

`setTimeout(myfunction(parameter),200)`

meanwhile the code below work but it does not get the job done cause i cant pass a parameter.can anyone explain why ?

`setTimeout(myfunction,200)`

Comment: `myfunction(parameter)` calls the function immediately and passes whatever it returns as callback to `setTimeout`…

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myfunction(parameter);
}, 200)
```

You can also use

```
setTimeout(myfunction.bind(null, parameter), 200);
```